# How to prove this inequality? $ | z-1 | \le | | z | -1 | + | z| \cdot | \arg z | $

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

If $z$ is any non-zero complex number, how to prove the following inequality?
$$ | z-1 | \le | | z | -1 | + | z| \cdot | \arg z | $$

Hints please!

Comment: What are $\|z\|$ and $\|\arg z\|$? $|z|$ and $|\arg z|$?

Comment: I didn't know $ \| z \| $ and $| z |$ are different. (They are?) I thought that was the notation used here. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let U, V and W denote the points of affixes $1$, $z$ and $|z|$ respectively. Then:

- The LHS is the distance between U and V.
- The first term on the RHS is the distance between U and W.
- The second term on the RHS is the length of the arc of the circle of radius $|z|$ between V and W.

Conclude by noting that UV is at most the sum of UW and WV and that WV is less than the length of the arc.

Comment: Why is it that UV is at most the sum of UW and WV? I drew the diagram but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Every distance satisfies the axiom of triangular inequality.

Comment: Well yeah that should've been obvious! Thanks.

Comment: One more thing: what's the difference between $\| z \| $ and $| z |$?

Comment: $\|z\|$ does not exist.

Comment: So what is the $\| \text{blob} \|$ notation used for?

Comment: For norms on general normed spaces.

Comment: Ok. Understood (that it's different - not what it is). Won't use it now onward.